# Setting JavaMail Proxy For Spring Integration

Tags: tomcat, proxy, jakarta-mail, spring-integration

I have a Spring Integration process created to process email messages programatically. It works fine from my IDE, but fails when I deploy it to our Tomcat Unix server. 
I'm running JDK 1.6.0.4, Tomcat 7.0.29,  Grails 2.0.4, Spring Integration 2.1.3, and JavaMail 1.4.5. I'm trying to figure out how to get proxy settings configured so that I can run this. I've seen posts from 2010 saying that it's not possible, but it looks like there are JavaMail properties for it now.

I did try setting `-DsocksProxyHost=myproxy.mycompany.com` in the Tomcat `setenv.sh`, but my app failed before it even got to the mail part because it then couldn't access internal sites (like our datatbase connection)

I've looked at the [JavaMail API - FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#proxy) and I think I'm setting things up correctly, but it keeps timing out.

Has anyone successfully setup email proxies for Spring Integration processes?

Snippet from my Spring Integration XML file:

```
<util:properties id="javaMailProperties">
    <prop key="mail.imap.socketFactory.class">javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory</prop>
    <prop key="mail.imap.socketFactory.fallback">false</prop>
    <prop key="mail.store.protocol">imaps</prop>
    <prop key="mail.debug">true</prop>
    <prop key="mail.smtp.socks.host">socksproxy.mycompany.com</prop>
    <prop key="mail.smtp.socks.port">1080</prop>
    <prop key="mail.imap.socks.host">socksproxy.mycompany.com</prop>
    <prop key="mail.imap.socks.port">1080</prop>
</util:properties>

<mail:inbound-channel-adapter id="imapAdapter"
                              store-uri="imaps://myEmailAddress:myPassword@imap.gmail.com/INBOX"
                              java-mail-properties="javaMailProperties"
                              channel="receiveEmailChannel"
                              should-delete-messages="false"
                              should-mark-messages-as-read="true"
                              auto-startup="true">
    <int:poller max-messages-per-poll="1" fixed-rate="15" time-unit="SECONDS">
    </int:poller>
</mail:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

## Solution

Based on Bill Shannon's response, I updated my `javaMailProperties` to the snippet below and everything is working as expected.

```
<util:properties id="javaMailProperties">
    <prop key="mail.store.protocol">imaps</prop>
    <prop key="mail.imap.ssl.enable">true</prop>
    <prop key="mail.debug">true</prop>
    <prop key="mail.imaps.socks.host">socksproxy.mycompany.com</prop>
    <prop key="mail.imaps.socks.port">1080</prop>
</util:properties>
```

I think it's important to point out the fine print from the [JavaDocs](http://javamail.kenai.com/nonav/javadocs/com/sun/mail/imap/package-summary.html)...

> **Note that if you're using the "imaps" protocol to access IMAP over SSL, all the properties would be named "mail.imaps.*"**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's at least two problems...

First, [you don't need the socket factory settings](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).

Second, you're using the `imaps` protocol, but setting properties for the `imap` protocol.

Either set `mail.store.protocol` to `imap` and set `mail.imap.ssl.enable` to `true`, or change all the `mail.imap.*` properties to `mail.imaps.*` properties.

Comment: Thanks Bill. Based on [this Gmail documentation](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=78799), I think I need to keep the `imaps` SSL protocol. I will take out the factory settings as well. I'm definitely a victim of the internet cut and paste settings on this one, but I'm trying to learn. 

The [com.sun.mail.imap javadocs](http://javamail.kenai.com/nonav/javadocs/com/sun/mail/imap/package-summary.html) shows that `mail.imap.ssl.enable` defaults to false for the "imap" protocol and true for the "imaps" protocol, but I'll try setting it explicitly.

Comment: I don't see an `imaps` setting for socks host or other proxy. I see some `imap.ssl` settings, but none for proxies. Am I missing something?

Comment: I am missing something... Fine print from the JavaDocs...
_Note that if you're using the "imaps" protocol to access IMAP over SSL, all the properties would be named "mail.imaps.*"._

Comment: Thanks you! Worked like a charm. I think the `imaps` settings are what did it.